Is there an fmt view for nested calls?
Sometimes, I need to effectively call fmt::format in a nested manner. e.g.
fmt::format("{}", fmt::format("{}", arg));

The real situation is more complicated than this, of course.
I'd like a view for the nested calls so that it doesn't allocate a string, do the formatting, and then allocate another one for the outer call.
Does such a thing exist?

I think the closest thing for you to consider is std::format_to, which writes to an iterator. Which, of course, also means you are "unnesting" these calls.

@ChristianStieber that's very clever, but you probably still need two buffers. If you use the same buffer for both the input and output to std::format_to, you might run into UB (see What happens if formatting arguments alias the output buffer in std::format_to?). Even though the current wording doesn't seem to make it UB, I highly suspect that it's not intended to be valid. I'm currently doing some investigating on this issue.

@JanSchultke I did not realize that you wanted to use the same buffers for both input and output -- that would indeed make things complicated. Using format_to merely eliminates the need for intermediate strings because all your output is assembled into the final string, and if you can make a decent estimate on the length of the expected output you can even reserve() it beforehand (and still be safe if it's too small).

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78541679/
