Is there a "recursive" std::format?
I have some code like this:
const std::string first = "|>first {} thing<|";
const std::string second = "|>second thing<|";
const std::string third = "|>third thing<|";
const std::string fourth = "|>fourth thing<|";
const std::string out = std::format("Testing {} format {} string {}", first, second, third, fourth);
std::cout << out << std::endl;

This code outputs the following:
Testing |>first {} thing<| format |>second thing<| string |>third thing<|

I would like the code to output:
Testing |>first |>second thing<| thing<| format |>third thing<| string |>fourth thing<|

The difference is the |>first {} thing<| has been replaced by |>first |>second thing<| thing<|. That is, the format is applied recursively. std::format has a lot of compile time checks, but in theory nothing is stopping std::vformat from being able to be applied recursively.
Before I implement this functionality on my own, I would like to know whether it exists in the standard library, or if another robust solution is already available.
Real world example:
I have five (about 40 really) different queries all which need data1, data2, data3, ... just in a different location. The data will be known at runtime, but the position will be known at compile time. I have the option of five different query classes, or one templated with different specializations: using Query1 = BasicQuery("BLAH {} BLAH"); using Query2 = BasicQuery("BLAH BLAH {}"); so on. This can be the difference in both 1500 lines of code vs ~250 and a nicer calling interface vs a convoluted one (single execute function per class, vs a function per query if I chose to just have one class with all the queries).
Additionally, adding a function per query is not a choice. Each query has a different return type (and indeed different number of returns) based on the nature of the query. The class also handles parsing the returned data based on the return type and number of returns. Template specializations are a really nice solution to this. I am hoping I can also use the specializations for the query string itself.

What a nightmare of functionality. Why would anyone need it?

@n.m.couldbeanAI For example, if you have five different queries all which need data1, data2, data3, ... just in a different location. The data will be known at runtime, but the position at compile time, then you have the option of five different queries (class or function), or one templated with different specializations: using Query1 = BasicQuery("BLAH {} BLAH"); using Query2 = BasicQuery("BLAH BLAH {}"); so on. This can be the difference in both 1500 lines of code vs ~250 and a nicer calling interface vs a convoluted one (single execute function per class, vs a function per query).

I dont understand this sentence " ...but in theory nothing is stopping std::vformat from being able to do so." to do what? apply compile time checks?

Could you please edit your question with the real-world example you have in the comments? (Although I don't see how the nesting behavior is useful there) Otherwise we might suggest something that is not generic enough.

@463035818_is_not_an_ai std::format checks the format string at compile time. It is possible one of the recursive strings is unknown until runtime. Therefore, std::format cannot verify it. std::vformat exists as a entirely runtime variant of std::format. By "to do so" I mean function recursively as compile time knowledge is irrelevant for std::vformat.

@Botje I updated it

frankly, the description of your use case is vague. Don't focus only on what you consider as solution, but let us follow that way from the beginning. This is a xy problem you are convinced that y solves x, but we are still missing a complete understanding of x. Try to create a [mcve]. YOu dont have to show 40 different queries, not even 5 but actually showing the code for 2 would help a lot

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I see, I'll prototype something in compile explorer. Give me a few minutes, please.

its a general symptom of questions that aim to avoid writing code. You do not show us the code you want to avoid to write. Now consider someone knows how to solve the problem without writing that code you want to avoid, for them it will not be obvious what code you are talking about, because they wouldnt write it

Based on your description, I think it would be much better would be to use substitution based on a dictionary to index the elements, like in pythonish "{a} {b}".format(a=1, b=1). Also why not BasicQuery("BLAH {} BLAH", "data");. Note that you are asking XY question. You specifically ask for existestence of recursive std::format, not how to write clean code using templated queries, or similar. Also, it's quite very hard to answer if something exists or not in the world - no one I know posseses such power.

Use fixed strings literals and put the format string in the type. Then just type erase it.


Is there a "recursive" std::format?

No, there is not. You would have to write one yourself.


I have the option of five different query classes, or one templated

Consider using a templating engine.
My 1 min search for https://www.google.com/search?q=C%2B%2B+templating+engine resulted in Is there a good template engine for C++ , https://jinja2cpp.github.io/ and https://github.com/pantor/inja .
